# Removing trailing slashes generates absolute file path

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

### Behavior

If I go to: `http://localhost/login`
... everything works as acceptected

If I go to: `http://localhost/login/`
.. I get redirected to: `http://localhost/var/www/public/login`

**Expected behavior** is for the trailing slash to be removed:
`http://localhost/login/` ***=>>*** `http://localhost/login`

#### .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

## Question

1. Why doesn't it work as expected?
2. How do I make it work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule for removing trailing slash (using **non-greedy regex**):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

*There might be nothing wrong with your example. Try clearing your cache and it should work..*

Comment: Made an edit, try it and make sure to test in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: Yupp, still the same issue though

Comment: but clearing the cache worked for my first solution ... so thanks anyway.

Comment: I have added your suggested edit to my answer. Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.